# OCaml- local variables in if-else block?

Tags: if-statement, functional-programming, ocaml

How would you make a local variable within an if-else block? (if that's valid in Ocaml)

Here's example code in C of what I'm trying to do in OCaml:

```
if (1 == 1) {
        return 3;
    } else {
        int j = 5;
        return j;
    }
```

Comment: Look at it like this: a if-then-else is an expression, that is evaluated and returns a value. Not a do this, define that construction. Especially you can't define variables to be used outside.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to realize that variables in OCaml are immutable, i.e., they are bound to a value when declared, and the value is never changed.

If you're comfortable with this meaning of "variable", then you can declare local variables anywhere an expression can appear. An expression of the form

```
let v = expr1 in expr2
```

declares a variable `v` that's local to `expr2`. Its value (which can never be changed) is given by `expr1`.

You can use this kind of expression anywhere, hence you can use it in an if expression.

A reasonably faithful translation of your C code would be something like this:

```
if 1 = 1 then
    3
else
    let j = 5 in
    j
```

Answer (score 1):

This is valid but not very useful.

```
let i=1;;
if i = 1 then 
  3 
else ( 
  let j=5 in
  j
) ;;
```

- : int = 3